# Angular - Como reutilizar informações de um componente em outro para realizar condição?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Eu tenho um menu no meu componente html da seguinte forma: (MenuComponent.html)

```
<p-tabMenu class="tabMenuDrograria" #menuItems [model]="items" [activeItem]="items[0]"
       (click)="ativarMenu()"></p-tabMenu>

<div class="tab-box" *ngIf="menuAtivado() === 'ROSARIO'">
<aop-drogaria-rosario></aop-drogaria-rosario>
</div>
<div class="tab-box cor-base" *ngIf="menuAtivado() === 'SP'">
 <aop-drogaria-sao-paulo></aop-drogaria-sao-paulo>
</div>
<div class="tab-box cor-base" *ngIf="menuAtivado() === 'SM'">
<aop-drogaria-santa-marta></aop-drogaria-santa-marta>
</div>
<div class="tab-box cor-base" *ngIf="menuAtivado() === 'DEMAIS'">
  <aop-drogaria-demais></aop-drogaria-demais>
</div>
```

E no TypeScript desse componete,(MenuComponent.ts) tenho funções que ativam esse menu e atribuem seus respectivos ID para a apresentação na tela:

```
public items: MenuItem[];
public itemAtivado: MenuItem;

ngOnInit() {

this.items = [
  {label: 'ROSARIO',  id: 'ROSARIO'},
  {label: 'SAO PAULO',  id: 'SP'},
  {label: 'SANTA MARTA', id: 'SM'},
  {label: 'DEMAIS', id: 'DEMAIS'},
];
}

ativarMenu() 
this.itemAtivado = this.menu['activeItem'];

 }
menuAtivado() {
return this.itemAtivado != null ? this.itemAtivado.id : 'ROSARIO';
```

}

O menu funciona fielmente. Quando clico na aba de Drogaria Rosario por exemplo, é exibido o componente  (DrogariaRosario.component.html) e se eu clicar na aba de SP é exibido o  (DrogariaSaoPaulo.component.html). O que acontece é que todos os componentes tem dentro deles embutido a reutilização de um outro componente chamado Drogarias  (Drogarias.component.html). Dentro dele há um html que organiza todos esses componentes. Ou seja se eu for em qualquer um dos componentes de remedios, dentro deles terá um . Que os leva até o seguinte código html reutilizado para todas as drogarias:

```
 <div *ngFor="let remedio of remedios" >
<div class="nome"><br/>
   Nome do Remédio:{{remedio.nome}}
</div>
<div clas="data">
   Data de Fabricação:{{remedio.data}}
</div>
<div class="descricao">
   Descrição do Remédio:{{remedio.descricao}}<br/>
</div>
<div class="informacao">
  Informação nutricional:{{remedio.informacaoNutricional}}
</div>
</div>
```

O que preciso saber é como limitar algumas informações para cada menu que for clicado, por exemplo. Se eu clicar na drogaria rosário não quero que exiba a informação nutricionais dos remédios. Eu teria que fazer um *ngIF, mas não sei como trazer essa informação do componente do menu. Como saber qual componente está sendo clicado para restringir nesse *ngIf?

Answer (score 0):

Uma ideia seria ter dentro do componente drogarias um @Input() pra cada atributo que você quer exibir, assim você consegue colocar um *ngIf para esconder quando não for usar, não sei como está seu componente drogaria, mas ficaria mais ou menos assim pelo que eu entendi da arquitetura que vc está usando, no drogaria.component.ts

```
@Input() exibeNome: boolean;
@Input() exibeData: boolean;
@Input() exibeDesc: boolean;
@Input() exibeInfo: boolean;
```

O @Input vem de '@angular/core';

Ai dentro do drogaria-demais.component.html e nos outros componentes que chama o drogaria.component.html vc coloca assim:

```
<aop-drogaria [exibeNome]="True" [exibeData]="False" [exibeDesc]="True" [exibeInfo]="False"></aop-drogaria>
```

e finalmente no seu código html do drogaria.component.html vc coloca assim:

```
<div *ngFor="let remedio of remedios">
    <div *ngIf="exibeNome" class="nome"><br />
        Nome do Remédio:{{remedio.nome}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="exibeData" clas="data">
        Data de Fabricação:{{remedio.data}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="exibeDesc" class="descricao">
        Descrição do Remédio:{{remedio.descricao}}<br />
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="exibeInfo" class="informacao">
        Informação nutricional:{{remedio.informacaoNutricional}}
    </div>
</div>
```